# httpwebresponse special characters

Tags: httpwebrequest

This is on pocket pc. I'm using httpwebrequest to connect to a classic asp page to send and receive requests/responses. It was working fine all these years for almost 8 years, but now there are some special characters like "Tokaji Aszú Apple", note the 'u' is different. The response replaces 'ú' with '?'.
I need to have it as-is.

I verified it with a test.asp page and browsed it from browser, it displays correctly.

```
<%
response.write "Tokaji Aszú Apple/ Fuji"
%>
```

but when I call the same page using httpwebrequest the response has '?' instead of 'ú'.

Not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's old Asp try this one

ASP CODE:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

and the following HTML META tag:

Comment: Awesome! actually when I set the Encoding to UTF8 on StreamReader constructor it kinda worked but it didn't display well on the device. Then added the 4 lines of code you gave me, it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put UTF8 encoding to content
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8

Comment: I couldn't, it says the property is ReadOnly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one Response.Charset = "UTF-8";

Comment: I found the answer on another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638756/httpwebrequest-receiving-response-with-the-right-encoding to use encoding on StreamReader constructor, it works